# How to pass string as value in mapper?

Tags: string, hadoop, mapper, writable

I am trying to pass a string as value in the mapper, but getting error that it is not Writable. How to resolve?

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String TempString = value.toString();
    String[] SingleRecord = TempString.split("\t");

    //using Integer.parseInt to calculate profit
    int Amount = Integer.parseInt(SingleRecord[7]);
    int Asset = Integer.parseInt(SingleRecord[8]);
    int SalesPrice = Integer.parseInt(SingleRecord[9]);
    int Profit = Amount*(SalesPrice-Asset);

    String ValueProfit = String.valueOf(Profit);
    String ValueOne = String.valueOf(one);

    custID.set(SingleRecord[2]);
    data.set(ValueOne + ValueProfit);
    context.write(custID, data);

}
```

Comment: What is `data` and what is `custId`?

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo's tutorial says :
***Objects which can be marshaled to or from files and across the network must obey a particular interface, called Writable, which allows Hadoop to read and write the data in a serialized form for transmission.***

From Cloudera site :
***The key and value classes must be serializable by the framework and hence must implement the Writable interface. Additionally, the key classes must implement the WritableComparable interface to facilitate sorting.***

So you need an implementation of `Writable` to write it as a value in the context. Hadoop ships with a few  stock classes such as `IntWritable`. The `String` counterpart you are looking for is the `Text` class. It can be used as :

```
context.write(custID, new Text(data));
```

OR

```
Text outValue = new Text();
val.set(data);
context.write(custID, outValue)
```

I case, you need specialized functionality in the value class, you may implement `Writable` (not a big deal after all). However seems like `Text` is just enough for you.

Comment: we tried your suggestion, but still getting an error: Multiple markers at this line
 - The constructor Text(IntWritable) is undefined
 - The method write(Text, TextWritable) in the type 
  TaskInputOutputContext<LongWritable,Text,Text,TextWritable> is not applicable for the arguments 
  (Text, Text)

Comment: Perhaps `data` is an `IntWritable`. Please share complete code of your `Mapper` to get a quick solution.

Comment: `public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String TempString = value.toString();
    String[] SingleRecord = TempString.split("\t");
    int Amount = Integer.parseInt(SingleRecord[7]);
    int Asset = Integer.parseInt(SingleRecord[8]);
    int SalesPrice = Integer.parseInt(SingleRecord[9]);
    int Profit = Amount*(SalesPrice-Asset);
    String ValueProfit = String.valueOf(Profit);
    String ValueOne = String.valueOf(one);
    custID.set(SingleRecord[2]);
    context.write(custID, new Text(data));
}`

Comment: I indeed meant `Mapper` - the whole class, not only the `map` method, which you've already shared. The main issue with `data` - it's definitely not a string. Or you've messed up with imports.

Answer (score 0):

you havent set data in map function according to import text in above,and TextWritable is wrong just use Text as well.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! It will be a lot helpful to provide a code snippet or an example (see [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)).